# what is a seepage pit invert

Tags: plumbing

My local code requires the seepage pit "invert" to be 2 feet above the water table.

what is the seepage pit invert? is it at the top or the bottom of the pit?

Answer (score 2):

It's the lowest point in the pit. See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/382388/pipe-invert-and-obvert-why-is-it-called-invert.